# DSV : Custome Scenario Provider - NullPointerException

Tags: ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

I'm trying to create **Custom Scenario Provider for Rule Designer** and have created a **Plug-in** to execute it through Run Configurations. I'm able to create the plug-in and run DVS Runner; however, I'm receiving **NullPointerException in IlrDVSRunner**. I'm unable to resolve the exception through all means. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**MotorScenarioProvider.java**

```
public class MotorScenarioProvider implements IlrScenarioProvider, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 20150702L;

public MotorScenarioProvider() {
    super();
    System.out.println("MotorScenarioProvider - Constructor");
}

public void initialize(IlrScenarioSuiteExecutionContext context)
        throws IlrInitializationException {
    System.out.println("MotorScenarioProvider - Initialize");
}

public int getScenarioCount() throws IlrScenarioProviderException {
    System.out.println("MotorScenarioProvider - getScenarioCount");
    return 1;
}

public IlrScenario getScenarioAt(int indx)
        throws IlrScenarioProviderException {
    System.out.println("MotorScenarioProvider - getScenarioAt");

    IlrScenarioImpl scenario = new IlrScenarioImpl();
    Map<String, Object> inputParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    //Setting Blank Scenario for testing purpose
    scenario.setName("Scenario 1");
    inputParameters.put("req", new Object());
    inputParameters.put("req", new Object());
    scenario.setInputParameters(inputParameters);

    return scenario;
}
```

**MotorScenarioProviderRunner.java**

```
public class MotorScenarioProviderRunner extends IlrDVSRunner {
/**
 * Create a DVS scenario suite descriptor
 * 
 * @return The scenario suite descriptor
 */
public IlrScenarioSuiteDescriptor createScenarioSuiteDescriptor() {
    IlrScenarioSuiteDescriptorFactory scenarioSuiteDescriptorFactory = new IlrScenarioSuiteDescriptorFactory();
    IlrScenarioFormatDescriptor formatDescriptor = IlrScenarioFormatDescriptorFactory
            .getInstance().createScenarioFormatDescriptor();
    formatDescriptor
        .setScenarioProviderClassName(MotorScenarioProvider.class.getName());
    IlrScenarioSuiteDescriptor suiteDescriptor = scenarioSuiteDescriptorFactory
            .createScenarioSuiteDescriptor(formatDescriptor);
    suiteDescriptor.setKPIEnabled(false);
    suiteDescriptor.setTestEnabled(true);
    suiteDescriptor.setProductionRulesetArchive(new IlrRulesetArchive());
    System.out.println("MotorScenarioProviderRunner: createScenarioSuiteDescriptor");

    suiteDescriptor.add("SCENARIO_NAME", "Scenario 1");

    return suiteDescriptor;
}

/**
 * The main method run from the {@link IlrDVSLaunchConfigurationDelegate}
 * launch method.
 * 
 * @param args
 *            The args needed to run the scenarios and build the scenario
 *            suite descriptor.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MotorScenarioProviderRunner runner = new MotorScenarioProviderRunner();
    String[] data = runner.extractCustomArgs(args);
    // TODO read the custom parameters from the 'data' attribute and not
    // from the 'args' attribute
    System.out.println("MotorScenarioProviderRunner: main");

    try {
        IlrScenarioSuiteDescriptor scenarioSuite = runner
                .createScenarioSuiteDescriptor();

        if(scenarioSuite == null)
            System.out.println("scenarioSuite is NULL");
        if(args == null)
            System.out.println("args is NULL");

        runner.run(args, scenarioSuite); **//EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE**
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution of this.

Actually, IlrDVSRunner.Run methods looks for type of launch configuration i.e. Run or Debug at 3 place in the *custum args* auto inserted from launch config.

The first arg in *custom args* is the custom data we gonna provide to DVS Runner. In my case, it was my *Scenario Provider class* which adds the data to scenario. So, when I updated the launch configuation to put a *Text-Box*  which will provide the *Scenario Provider class* name to my custom scenario provider, eventually I end-up with solution of my problem.

Here is my XML Scenario Provider which can be used to *run\debug* XMLs directly in **Rule Designer**: [XML Scenario Provider](https://odm4rules.wordpress.com/2015/09/30/xml-scenario-provider/)

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't loaded the ruleset archive.

Instead of:

```
suiteDescriptor.setProductionRulesetArchive(new IlrRulesetArchive());
```

Use something along the lines of:

```
JarInputStream is = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(rulesetJar));
IlrRulesetArchive ruleset = IlrRulesetArchive.extractArchive(new IlrJarArchiveLoader(is));
suiteDescriptor.setProductionRulesetArchive(ruleset);
```

Comment: I have already tried this long before your response. But still NullPointerException.